# How does one say olive oil eardrops in French?

Tags: pronoms, verbes, adjectifs, noms, de

How does one say 'olive oil eardrops' in French? I think it is 'les gouttes d'huile d'olive pour les oreilles.' Is that correct? It seems far too long.

Comment: Possibly « gouttes auriculaires à l'huile d'olive »

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might say

> *gouttes auriculaires à l'huile d'olive*

or

> *gouttes auriculaires à base d'huile d'olive*